# Fourier font not used when compiling with LuaLateX since new year

Tags: luatex, fourier

The fourier font is not used in the following mwe file when compiling with LuaLateX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier,esvect}

\begin{document}
\section{pretend 1} 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item one font check $\vv{AB}$
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

It works when compiling with pdfLateX. This problem is recent. I have other bigger files that still were outputting correctly the font with LuaLateX as of 12/28/19. The system on my old computer also still outputs correctly.

I use Windows and MikTeX 2.9. Unsuccessful attempts include the following:

- change editors but both TeXworks and TeXstudio fail to show fourier;
- clearing the cache file in names from luatex-cache;
- installing MikTeX on a different computer.

Any ideas? I need fourier in my original files for various math and nonmath reasons, and I need LuaLateX in some of the files because of a heavy use of pgfplots which leads to an error of memory exceeded with pdflatex (I tried some workaround on that for a while but LuaLateX proved to be the only reliable way to go).

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: One possible way this could happen is if you load a package that, if compiled on LuaLaTeX, loads `fontspec` or `unicode-math`, breaking your legacy 8-bit font packages.

Comment: You might be able to use Lingua Franca as an OpenType fork of the same font Fourier is based on.

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: The fourier-orns documentation (28-Nov-2019) says: "The old command \danger (fourier-orns 1.1) is now deprecated: use \warning instead. Note that \danger is still usable, provided you don’t use the unicode-math package."

Comment: `fourier` package loads `fontspec` if it detects it is running under an engine that uses TU encoding (lualatex, xelatex); and then grabs the warning sign glyph (U+26A0) directly from the Open Type font `FourierOrns` (in `\fonts\opentype\public\fourier`). Which means you can do the same, if you want (even with any glyph in the font). `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier,esvect}
%\usepackage{fontspec}%already loaded
\newfontfamily\myfourier{FourierOrns}
\newcommand\mydanger{{\myfourier ^^^^26a0}}
\begin{document}
 \warning 
 \mydanger
 $\vv{AB}$
\end{document}`

Comment: Thank you Cicada for the info about \danger, fourier and fontspec. This makes sense now. And Davislor, I'm not getting an error per se in the mwe but rather the text font in the output is lmodern instead of the one it should and used to be from fourier. And finally thank you Barbara,

Answer (score 5):

You can use the fourier package to setup math, but for the text you should better load an open type font with TU encoding, e.g. heuristica:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier}
\setmainfont{heuristica}[Scale=0.91]
\begin{document}
\section{pretend 1}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item one font check $abc$
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your answer works fine for the text in general. But one of the non math thing I use from fourier is the \danger sign. If I add that to the text above, the compiling fails with LuaLateX. It works (if I remove the \setmainfront line) in PDFLatex.

Comment: Update: I was able to replace \danger by \warning and it works now in LuaLateX. Hopefully there are no other fourier commands in other files that I need to replace.

Comment: It is not a problem to (re)define such commands if needed. Simply do e.g. \newcommand\danger{\warning}.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike. When I switched to lualatex for compiling for memory reasons, it first had issues with first run because of the esvect and esint packages. So I used your suggestion from 3 years ago in a post: "So in miktex one has to first call pdflatex which triggers the creation of the tfm and can then use them with lualatex." This worked until my new system in December where now lualatex has problems with fourier.