# Font issues with LuaLaTeX and polyglossia

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, polyglossia, fourier

After a recent TeX Live update, my documents, which used to compile properly, are now typeset with a wrong font. I then unsuccessfully tried to understand how I should do fonts "the right way". Since I am under time pressure, I hope it is okay to just ask here for a solution to my problem.

I have tried four scenarios:

### 1 Compilation with pdfLaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{My \textbf{header}}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
My \textbf{text} and \textbf{equation}:
\begin{align}
F_\text{G}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Compiling the MWE above with pdfLaTeX produces:
[image]
This looks fine.

### 2 Compilation with LuaLaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{My \textbf{header}}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
My \textbf{text} and \textbf{equation}:
\begin{align}
F_\text{G}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Compiling the MWE above with LuaLaTeXproduces:
[image]
All fonts except the normalsize math font are wrong.

### 3 Adding `fontspec`

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{My \textbf{header}}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
My \textbf{text} and \textbf{equation}:
\begin{align}
F_\text{G}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Compiling the MWE above with LuaLaTeXproduces:
[image]
This looks fine.

### 4 Adding `polyglossia`

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{My \textbf{header}}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
My \textbf{text} and \textbf{equation}:
\begin{align}
F_\text{G}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Compiling the MWE above with LuaLaTeXproduces:
[image]
Regular text and the math index are wrong now.

This behavior only occurred after the TeX Live update. Has there been a significant change?

### Questions

My goal is to use the fonts I used to get with the `fouriernc` package, use `polyglossia` (I have issues with `babel` and `isodate` with the language set to `nswissgerman`), and compile with LuaLaTeX.

1. Is this possible?
2. What is the simplest, most lightweight (i.e. of compiling time) way to achieve this? Is it, for example, possible to set my desired font(s) with `fontspec` instead of loading `fouriernc`?

Thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522943/2388. Using fouriernc or fourier to setup text fonts is simply wrong for lualatex (and always was)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks for your reply! I am, however, confused as you use fourier in your MWE on that page. What would be a non-wrong way to use the fonts in fouriernc or similar? Btw, do you know of a list like https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html of LuaLaTeX-compatible fonts, possibly with instructions of proper use?

Comment: My MWE then resets the text font.

Comment: But without loading fourier, ``\setmainfont`` is undefined. So fourier does seem to be doing something useful. On the other hand you said using fourier is simply wrong for lualatex. So I wonder how to do things properly. (Sorry for insisting and my ignorance.)

Comment: fourier (at least newer versions) load fontspec, and this resets the main font to latin modern.

Comment: So is using fourier not so wrong then after all? I am just hoping for a simple, clear-cut answer. But even though this is interesting, I am still not closer to solving my problem. What really bugs me is that everything used to work until the update...

Comment: “I have issues with `babel` and `isodate` with the language set to `nswissgerman`.” // Please, could you report these issues, to fix them?

Comment: @JavierBezos, sorry, could you maybe point me to where I can do that?

Comment: Either in GitHub, which is the preferred method ( https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues ) or also here: http://www.texnia.com/contact.html .

Answer (score 3):

`fouriernc` loads `fourier`, and this loads `fourier-orns`, and newer version of this package loads (with xelatex and lualatex) the `fontspec` package.

`fontspec` changes the font encoding to `TU` (that is the suitable encoding for the unicode engines). As fourier doesn't setup its text fonts for `TU` the text fonts now fall back to lmr:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/fnc/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 6.
```

The math font setup is not affected.

To best way to get suitable text fonts is to set them up with \setmainfont. As `fouriernc` loads fontenc and setup math font, it is best to load it early, so that fontspec can take over correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{fouriernc}%loads fontspec
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{heuristica}[Scale=0.91]
\begin{document}
My \textbf{text} and \textbf{equation}:
\begin{align}
F_\text{G}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]